# How to print two columns with different range using for loops?

Tags: python

I need some very basic help with Python. I'm trying to get a better understanding of formatting using a for loop and I want to print out vertical Histogram.

Here is what I've tried:

```
tot_progress = 2
tot_trailer = 4
tot_retriever = 3
tot_exclude = 4
# Vertical Histogram
print("Progress", " Trailing", " Retriever", " Excluded")
a = '*'
for i,j,k,l in zip(range(0, tot_progress, 1), range(0, tot_trailer, 1), range(0, tot_retriever, 1), range(0, tot_exclude, 1)):
    print('{}\t\t\t{}\t\t\t{}\t\t\t{}'.format(a, a, a, a))
```

The output I got:

```
Progress  Trailing  Retriever  Excluded
   *         *          *         *
   *         *          *         *
```

what I want:

```
Progress  Trailing  Retriever  Excluded
   *         *          *         *
   *         *          *         *
             *          *         *
             *                    *
```

Comment: Maybe use `itertools.zip_longest()`.

Comment: Or, if you want to code it yourself, find the longest list, then pad out the shorter lists to that length with a placeholder value you don't print or a whitespace character instead of `*`

Comment: Side note: with your range function calls, if you are starting at 0 and stepping by 1, you can just leave these arguments out and simply call range(tot_progress) and similar. It will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

User itertools longest to iterate to maximum and update your loop with conditions and print accordingly

```
import itertools

for i,j,k,l in itertools.zip_longest(range(0, tot_progress, 1), range(0, tot_trailer, 1), range(0, tot_retriever, 1), range(0, tot_exclude, 1)):
    ai="*" if not i == None else " "
    aj="*" if not j == None else " "
    ak="*" if not k == None else " "
    al="*" if not l == None else " "
    print('{}\t\t\t{}\t\t\t{}\t\t\t{}'.format(ai, aj, ak, al))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have *vertical* histograms you can format each row to have the same "length" and then `zip`, so that you can transpose it properly. Used string formatting layout, see [here](https://pyformat.info/) for details.

Each bar of the histogram will be *centered* wrt to the label of the column.

```
col_labels = {'Progress statussss': 2, "Trailing": 8, "Retriever": 3, "Excluded": 4}

SYMBOL = '*'
PADDING = 2 # add extra space between two columns

col_sizes = list(map(len, col_labels))

row_template = [(('{S:^' + f'{size + PADDING}' + '}' + ' ') *v)[:-1].split() + [' ' * (size+PADDING) ]*(size - v) for size, v in zip(col_sizes, col_labels.values())]

# column names
print(''.join(('{:^' + f'{col_sizes[i] + PADDING}' + '}').format(v) for i, v in enumerate(col_labels)))
# bars
for l in (''.join(i)  for i in zip(*row_template)):
    print(l.format(S=SYMBOL))
```

Output

```
 Progress statussss  Trailing  Retriever  Excluded 
         *              *          *         *     
         *              *          *         *     
                        *          *         *     
                        *                    *     
                        *                          
                        *                          
                        *                          
                        *
```