# Simple python histogram

Tags: python

```
result1 = ["Progress","Progress(MT)","ModuleRT","Exclude"]
result2 = [3,4,3,5]


def histogram (list1,list2):
    for i in range (len(list1)):
        print(list1[i])
        for j in range (list2[i]):
            print("","*")
histogram(result1,result2)
```

I'm trying to get the output like this, but I can't seem to get that.

```
Progress Progress(MT)  ModuleRT Excluded 
 *           *           *          * 
             *
```

Comment: does it help? [histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70009051/how-to-print-two-columns-with-different-range-using-for-loops/70010703#70010703)

Comment: but you example of histogram is not really related to your data in `result2`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Using center(), you can build the columns with the width corresponding to their respective title size.  The histogram itself will need as many lines as the maximum value in result2.  Each column should only print a star if the line index is less than the corresponding value.

```
result1 = ["Progress","Progress(MT)","ModuleRT","Exclude"]
result2 = [3,4,3,5]

print(*result1) 
for i in range(max(result2)):
    print(*( " *"[i<r].center(len(t)) for t,r in zip(result1,result2)))

Progress Progress(MT) ModuleRT Exclude
   *          *          *        *   
   *          *          *        *   
   *          *          *        *   
              *                   *   
                                  *
```

The histogram would look better if the columns were above the titles.  You can do this by simply reversing the order of the line index:

```
for i in reversed(range(max(result2))):
    print(*( " *"[i<r].center(len(t)) for t,r in zip(result1,result2)))
print(*result1)

                                  *   
              *                   *   
   *          *          *        *   
   *          *          *        *   
   *          *          *        *   
Progress Progress(MT) ModuleRT Exclude
```

Converted to a function:

```
def histogram(titles,values):
    print(*titles) 
    for i in range(max(values)):
        print(*( " *"[i<v].center(len(t)) for t,v in zip(titles,values)))
```

Comment: Thanx. This helped!
but is there a way to do this by altering the function I've defined?

Comment: You could put the 3 lines inside your function.  There is little that can be done with your existing loops.  1) processing of list2 should not be nested in the list1 loop because the titles need to go on the same line. 2) the main loop needs to take into account the number of lines to print, 3) the histogram stars need to print on the same line (i.e. every column for the number of lines needed)

Comment: I tried it like that but it didn't align

Comment: Probably a copy paste error, or you didn't change the names of the variables

Answer (score 0):

Hello Alex and welcome on the Stackoverflow

I assume that, you want to get something like this below:

```
Progress * * *
Progress(MT) * * * *
ModuleRT * * *
Exclude * * * * *
```

Then, you have to modify your code, so that the `print` method does not add a new line after every `*` printed. To do so, you use `end` argument and set it to an empty character, like this: `print("some string", end='')`

So your new code would be:

```
result1 = ["Progress","Progress(MT)","ModuleRT","Exclude"]
result2 = [3,4,3,5]


def histogram (list1,list2):
    for i in range (len(list1)):
        print(list1[i], end='') # here is the end added
        for j in range (list2[i]):
            print("","*", end='') # here is the end added
histogram(result1,result2)
```

Nevertheless, it won't end-up in something like this:

```
Progress * * *Progress(MT) * * * *ModuleRT * * *Exclude * * * * *
```

The thing is, that there's no new line character after first outer for loop iteration. So you print a new line with an empty print at the end of the outer loop like this `print("")`.

So finally your code would look like this:

```
result1 = ["Progress","Progress(MT)","ModuleRT","Exclude"]
result2 = [3,4,3,5]


def histogram (list1,list2):
    for i in range (len(list1)):
        print(list1[i], end='')
        for j in range (list2[i]):
            print("","*", end='')
        print("") # here is the print
histogram(result1,result2)
```

Comment: that's not really a histogram... the base of each bar starts right after the end of the label but they should be uniform (same starting point)

Comment: Thanx but I'm looking for a way to do that verically. Just like I've shown in the post